# Trying to create a filter but getting a type error

Tags: python

I am trying to make the filter to return all the numbers in the list that are greater than the average of the list:

```
import math

print("Example of filter")

x=[5,1,10,30,5,13,5,19,-58,100,-5,-23,0,32,12,13,4,19]

avg = sum(x) / len(x) #Finding the average of the numbers in x.

print(avg)

if avg>x:
   print(x)
```

But I'm getting this error below:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'list'
```

Comment: Comparison is wrong as a list data structure cannot be compared with a float data type. You should iterate over the list and compare individual element x[i] with average and print the individual element.

Comment: You forgot to **loop** over the list (`for y in x`). What do you expect a comparison between a number and a list to yield?

Answer (score 1):

`avg` is of `int` type and `x` is list type. comparing a int with a  list is giving you error.

you need to iterate through the list `x` and check it's element greater then `avg` or not.

you can do this as

```
 result = [i for i in x if i>avg]
 print(result)
```

or

```
 result = []
 for val in x:
     if val>avg:
         result.append(val)
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

print("Example of filter")

x=[5,1,10,30,5,13,5,19,-58,100,-5,-23,0,32,12,13,4,19]

avg = sum(x) / len(x) #Finding the average of the numbers in x.

print(avg)

result = []

for i in x:
    if avg < i:
       result.append(i)

print(result)
```

This works.

[image]

I think that was your desired output. Use the `for` loop to append the values greater than the average. Hope that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` for this purpose and save yourself from `loop`

```
import numpy as np

x=[5,1,10,30,5,13,5,19,-58,100,-5,-23,0,32,12,13,4,19]
x = np.array(x) #convert list to numpy array
avg = np.mean(x)
result = x[x>avg] 
result = list(result) #convert numpy array to list
```

**output**

```
[30, 13, 19, 100, 32, 12, 13, 19]
```